# Asynchronous call of Ajax and getJSON request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, progress-bar, getjson

I want to get a progressbar while my ajax request is loading. This is the code-snippet of my ftp-backup-system:
backup.php
- is running through some steps and saving the current step to $_SESSION["step"]
getStatus.php
- sending $_SESSION["step"] back to jquery

Problem:
The code first calls the ajax request to backup.php and AFTER its finished, it calls the getJSON to getStatus.php.
Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "backup.php",
   data: $("#form").serialize()
});

(function checkStatus() {
   $.getJSON("getStatus.php", function(data) {
      alert("I am called when backup.php is finished. Why?");
      # do some stuff, for example:
      # data[0] = true/false #finished or not
      # data[1] = $_SESSION["step"]
      if (data[0])
         setInterval(function(){ checkStatus(); }, 500);
      # progressbar-refresh to data[1]
   });
})();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you try: (function checkStatus() { console.log('called');  ...})  Is 'called' in console still be printed after previous ajax request has finished?

Comment: On each step you're creating a new interval with `setInterval(...)` which will therfor create a new interval with each step... - Use `setTimeout(checkStatus, 500)` instead

Comment: You want to display progress bar till both requests finishes, right?

Comment: Yes 'roested'.The function checkStatus() is called directly after the ajax request, but not the getJSON. The getJSON is first called, when the ajax request is finished.

Comment: Is the server possibly limited to a single thread? So server can't deal with second request until done with first?

Comment: 'Andreas' the setInterval method is not the problem, because its also first called when the getJSON request is called, and this is first called when the ajax request is finished.

Comment: 'pvnarula' while the backup is in progress (till the ajax request is not working anymore with backup.php) I want the progressbar, sequentially updated with the current step (saved in $_SESSION["step"])

Comment: That was not ment as a solution here hence I've posted it as a comment and not as an answer ;) It's just a hint for a later error which may arise from the usage of `setInterval`.

Comment: To address somebody add an `@` before the name - e.g. @Andreas or @NePheus

Comment: @NePheus ;) Is the web server single-threaded (see my previous comment)?

Comment: @mcNux Dual Intel Xeon 3GHz. But also single core processors can multithreading. I dont think that could be the reason for that kind of problem.

Comment: @NePheus The web server (e.g. Apache, IIS) could be configured to use a single thread is what I mean.

Comment: @mcNux where can I see if the server is configured to use a single thread?

Comment: @NePheus Depends on what you're using. But to start I'd try hitting the server with 2 requests simultaneously through browser. i.e. start request which takes ages to respond. start another request which should return instantly if thread available. See what happens!

Comment: Problem solved:

I use PHP SESSIONs in backup.php and getStatus.php and these are blocking each other. Working now with COOKIEs. Alternatively I could use a JSON file to store the steps...
I also changed
    setInterval(function(){ checkStatus(); }, 500);
to
    window.setTimeout(checkStatus, 500);
calling the getJSON request every 0.5 seconds.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

I use PHP SESSIONs in backup.php and getStatus.php and these are blocking each other. Working now with COOKIEs. Alternatively I could use a JSON file to store the steps...
I also changed
    setInterval(function(){ checkStatus(); }, 500);
to
    window.setTimeout(checkStatus, 500);
calling the getJSON request every 0.5 seconds.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I had also some problems with the COOKIES so I decided to use a JSON file to store the status. Now its working properly without any problems! :)